# Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo jest react-native

Tags: react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test the following describe block but an error comes in as:

`Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's`render`method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded`

```
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

jest.mock('react-native-intercom', () => 'Intercom')
jest.mock('react-native-push-notification', () => {
  return {
    configure: () => 'none'
  }
})
jest.mock('react-native-udp')
jest.mock('react-native-uuid')
jest.mock('react-native-localization')
jest.mock('react-native-google-signin', () => 'GoogleSignin')

import { Login } from '../'

describe('Containers',  () => {
  it('renders component correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Login  />
    ).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

I tried to look for many different guides, but was unable to get this working. The component in question is using refs, but normally there is no problem never. I tried to remove all duplicates react native, react or  any other possible source of react, unsuccessfully.

In my project I do have enzyme and I also tried to use it to record snapshots, but then there a document is required. shallow and render options do work using enzyme, but I would like to use the most comprehensive solution to test that components do work.

Comment: I get the same issue in my project. I have a thought if this is related to symlink. Are you using pnpm or yarn workspace?